# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

I am using JSLint to ensure my JavaScript is "strict" and I'm getting the following error:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

On the following code:
 
`if(index>0){
    shakStaute===1;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint is flagging up that `shakSuite===1;` is a pointless statement. The only thing it does is evaluate the variable `shakSuite`, compare its value with `1`, and then throw away the result of the comparison. It doesn't do anything else.

**If** your goal is to *set* `shakSuite` to the value `1`, you want `=` (assignment), not `===` (strict equality comparison):

```
if (index > 0) {
    shakSuite = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much